# How to model constraints without introducing additional variables?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, binary-variable

I have a binary variable $\bf x$ of size $12\times 1$, such as ${\bf x} =[x_1\hspace{1mm} x_2\hspace{1mm} x_3\hspace{1mm} x_4\hspace{1mm} x_5\hspace{1mm} x_6\hspace{1mm} x_7\hspace{1mm} x_8\hspace{1mm} x_9\hspace{1mm} x_{10}\hspace{1mm} x_{11}\hspace{1mm} x_{12} ]$

Now, they are grouped in 3 groups.

${\bf x} =[\{x_1\hspace{1mm} x_2\hspace{1mm} x_3\hspace{1mm} x_4\}\hspace{1mm} \{x_5\hspace{1mm} x_6\hspace{1mm} x_7\hspace{1mm} x_8\}\hspace{1mm} \{x_9\hspace{1mm} x_{10}\hspace{1mm} x_{11}\hspace{1mm} x_{12}\} ]$

The constraints I have are

1. Sum of all variables in each group is less than or equal to 2
   so,

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\le 2$

$x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8\le 2$

$x_9+x_{10}+x_{11}+x_{12}\le 2$

and

2. variables with same index in each group are equal. so

$x_1=x_5=x_9$

$x_2=x_6=x_{10}$

$x_3=x_7=x_{11}$

$x_4=x_8=x_{12}$

I can model the first set of constraints as

$\bf Bx\le2$

where $\bf B=[1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0;0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0;0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1\hspace{1mm} 1]$

How to model the second set of constraints without introducing additional variable?

I am looking for similar technique as used for the first set of constraints.

Comment: Hint: $C X = 0$ for an $8 \times 12$ matrix $C$ with coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: @RobPratt where does 8 in $8\times 12$ come from? Please give your detailed answer and the logic.

Comment: You have $8$ equality constraints: $x_1-x_5=0$, $x_1-x_9=0$, ...

Comment: @RobPratt thanks a lot!

Comment: @KGM, why not try to define the variable as $x_{i,j}$ (if variable $i$ appears in the group $j$)?